# javascript confirm box with if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, confirm

I'm trying to build a jacvascript running total calculator which allows the user to specify inputs which are sued to calculate a (sum) total which is shown on screen.

Before the user makes a change to the input I want to have a confirm box which allows the user to select okay (which leads to the new total being calculated) or cancel.

I've inserted the confirm box code with an IF statement into  the GetTotal function but it doesn't seem to be working. Every time the new total is calculated irrespective of whether the user selects okay or cancel. Any help greatly appreciated. Mike

```
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.1/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<script>
var input1 = 5555;
var input2 = 666;

$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("input1").value = input1;
  document.getElementById("input2").value = input2;
  GetFirstTotal();  
});

function GetFirstTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(index, value) {
      total += parseInt($(value).val() || 0);
    });

    $("#chkTotal").html(total);
}

function GetTotal() {
    var total = 0;
BootstrapDialog.confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?');
if(confirm("text")==1)
{  
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(index, value) {
      total += parseInt($(value).val() || 0);
    });

    $("#chkTotal").html(total);
}
else {}}
</script>

TOTAL:
<div id="chkTotal"></div>
<br>
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1"/>
<input type="button" value="Change X" onclick="GetTotal(this)"/>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2"/>
<input type="button" value="Change Y" onclick="GetTotal(this)"/>
```

Comment: I'd throw away any calculator that asks me if you really want it to do its job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Javascript [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) function should return a boolean value, so you should just be able to use :

```
if(confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?'))
{
      // Do these things
      $('input[type=text]').each(function(index, value) {
           total += parseInt($(value).val() || 0);
      });
      $("#chkTotal").html(total);
}
```

However, it appears that you are using the [BootstrapDialog](https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog) plug-in, which seems to operate a bit differently and accepts a callback to check the value that was entered :

[image]

So your code would likely look something like this, if you wanted to use it exclusively as a confirmation option :

```
BootstrapDialog.confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?', function(result){
   // If result is true, then the user confirmed the message
   if(result) {
         // Do work here
         $('input[type=text]').each(function(index, value) {
             total += parseInt($(value).val() || 0);
         });
         $("#chkTotal").html(total);
   }
});
```